# Validate time since a date using XPath 2

Tags: java, xpath-2.0

How (with which XPath expression) do I verify that a date on the format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" is older than a specific number of hours? I need to validate using Saxon's XPathExpression (XPath 2.0, Java 1.7). When calling...

```
xpathExpression.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.BOOLEAN)
```

...I want it to return true if the date is newer than, for examlple, 5 hours.

Lets say that the date is in the dt attribute of this XML:

```
<msgs>
    <msg dt="2012-04-04 12:13:14"/>
</msgs>
```

Thanks
Markus

Answer (score 1):

**The true XPath 2.0 solution is to use an XPath 2.0 expression like this**:

```
   current-dateTime() - xs:dateTime('2012-04-04T12:13:14')
 lt
   xs:dayTimeDuration('PT5H')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get into the nitty gritty, you could use substring to compute the time yourself, then compare the time value with the current date time:

Time you're analyzing:

```
boolean(100*number(substring(//msgs/msg/@dt,12,2)) + 10*number(substring(//msgs/msg/@dt,15,2)) + 1*number(substring(//msgs/msg/@dt,18,2)) > (current time + t*100))
```

where the current time is computed the same way, and t is the number of hours past that you're checking for. But this is considering the two times are on the same day, so if you want to check both, you'll have to do the same with the date value, so you're better off going with something on the lines of what Slanec is suggesting.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll go for the simpler Java solution :)